# Getting the biggest partition on server

Tags: partitioning, bash, sort

I'm trying to get the biggest partition out of "df -h" into a variable without success.

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            462M     0  462M   0% /dev
tmpfs            99M  5.7M   93M   6% /run
/dev/xvda1       25G   20G  3.5G  86% /
tmpfs           493M     0  493M   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs           493M     0  493M   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/loop0       88M   88M     0 100% /snap/go/4289
/dev/loop2       89M   89M     0 100% /snap/core/7270
/dev/loop1      6.8M  6.8M     0 100% /snap/amass/684
/dev/loop5       89M   89M     0 100% /snap/core/7396
/dev/loop4       88M   88M     0 100% /snap/go/4301
/dev/loop3      6.7M  6.7M     0 100% /snap/amass/687
tmpfs            99M  4.0K   99M   1% /run/user/133
tmpfs            99M     0   99M   0% /run/user/1000
```

as you can see "/" has the most disk space available on this server, and i want to set it into a variable.

However i will run this script on many servers so its not sure that "/" will be the partition with most available disk space. so i need that the partition with most available disk space will be set into the variable

Thanks!

Comment: You can get them in the right order with `df -h |sort -k 2 -h -r`, meaning: sort by the second field (`-k 2`). use humanly readable values (therefore 1G > 2M) and reverse the results. Now use `head` to get only the one at the top, and `cut` to get the name of the file system.

Comment: @Jos, Why don't you write an answer?

Answer (score 0):

following @Jos suggestion
it is now working using the following command "df -h |sort -k 2 -h -r |head -1|cut -b 39-70"
that will do the job, the 39 character is the start of the partition name.

Comment: `cut -b 39-70` seems quite unreliable to me....

Answer (score 0):

Limit `df` output to the fields you need, then it will be easier to `sort` and get the information needed:

```
df --output=size,target | sort -nr | awk 'NR==1{print $2}'
```

or `awk` only:

```
 df --output=size,target | awk '$1>s{s=$1;d=$2}END{print d}'
```

Note, that this will include network mounts, add `-l` to `df` command to show only local partitions.